# TypeORM insert using query builder and get entity back

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to insert an entity using `Entity.createQueryBuilder()` and get the entity back as one query. `.raw` returns only excluded fields for some reason and I want the opposite: I want to get the entity with all `@Exclude`-d fields excluded and others present. How to do this without making a separate query? I know about `.returning`, but I don't want to manually specify all the fields that I need. Maybe there's something like `.returnAllExceptExcluded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer here is to use `.returning('*')` and then decorate your controller with `ClassSerializerInterceptor`, like this:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class UserController {
  ...
}
`
```